# Flip a horizontal list into a vertical list, and a vertical list into a horizontal list

Tags: python

I want to create a function that flips a horizontal list into a vertical list, and a vertical list into a horizontal list. Like take a 1×n list (1 row and n columns) and flip it into an n×1 list (n rows and 1 column) and vice versa.

For example:

```
flip_list([1, 2, 3, 4]) ➞ [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
flip_list([[5], [6], [9]]) ➞ [5, 6, 9]
```

The first one is of horizontal to vertical and second one is vertical to horizontal.

I have tried few ways but couldn't get them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```py
def flip_list(lst):
    if not lst:
        return lst

    is_vertical = isinstance(lst[0], list)
    
    if is_vertical:
        return [el[0] for el in lst]
    
    return [[el] for el in lst]
```

---

First we check if the given `lst` is "truthy", see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). This will simply return `lst` if the list is empty or None, etc.

Your example showed that in a vertical list each element itself is another list containing the value, representing the columns.
That means we can determine if a list is vertical or horizontal when we look at the first element.

At this point we assume the list is not empty, since we checked beforehand. So we simply fetch the first element `lst[0]` and use the builtin [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check if it is an instance if the builtin list class.

To flip a list we use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). To convert vertical to horizontal we iterate each element of the list and write the first element of each one into the new list. Eliminating the columns.

```py
> lst = [[5], [6], [9]]
> [el[0] for el in lst]
[5, 6, 9]
```

Vice versa, we insert each element into a new list, creating the columns:

```py
> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
> [[el] for el in lst]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Comment: this is working. just asking if you can give a little explanation then it would be helpful.

Comment: I added some details, feel free to ask if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would have something like this:

```
def flip_list(list_flip):
    if isinstance(list_flip[0],list): return [x[0] for x in list_flip]
    else: return [[x] for x in list_flip]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this:

```
def flip_list(arr):
    return [j for i in arr for j in i] \
        if (isinstance(arr[0], list)) \
        else list(map(lambda x: [x], arr))


print(flip_list([[1, 2, 3], [2, 2], [3]]))
print(flip_list([1, 2, 3]))
print(flip_list([[1], [2], [3]]))

'''
Output: 
[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3]
[[1], [2], [3]]
[1, 2, 3]
'''
```